# Is there a max # of projects in QA as part of kanban?

Tags: kanban

Recently my place of work is switching from Scrum to kanban. In the process the QA tester mentioned that b/c they are a limited resource only 1 project can ever be in the QA testing column. I don't think this is a kanban standard at all. I thought it was only a max WIP for the team.
Is there a max in QA for kanban?

Answer (score 1):

Kanban is all about visualization of work in progress, its limits (because of queue theory) and optimization of lead and cycle times, so feedback can be gathered.

The meaning of each column in a Kanban board is contextual -  the team defines what is the structure and the rules for each column.

Wikpedia explains well what is a [Kanban board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_(development)#Kanban_boards) and [how work is managed in Kanban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_(development)#Managing_workflow).